# USB webcam too slow in taking photos on raspberry pi

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, usb, webcam, node-red

I'm using fswebcam to capture an image using node-red exec block running on a raspberry pi.
The time it takes to capture the image is 3+ seconds.

```
fswebcam -r 1280x720 image.jpg
```

I tried the same using OpenCV and the result is a little better but similar.

```
from cv2 import *
cam = VideoCapture(1)
s, img = cam.read()
if s:
    imwrite("/home/pi/pythontest/tt.jpg",img) #save image
    cam.release()
```

I'm guessing that it takes some time for the USB camera to initialize and take a picture which increases the time drastically. Is there any way to keep the camera initialized? 
Any other workarounds to ameliorate this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There may be other methods, but one way to do this is to run the camera continuously during periods when you want faster responses. You will need to consider some things though:

- bandwidth used to capture images
- wear on your SD card
- access incomplete images midway through capture.

---

I'll leave you to determine what USB bandwidth you need for the resolution you are using.

---

As regards the second - wear on your SD card - I would suggest you capture to `/tmp` and ensure that is based on a RAM filesystem by becoming `root` and adding a line like this to your `/etc/fstab`:

```
tmpfs   /tmp    tmpfs   defaults,noatime,nosuid 0   0
```

Then reboot. This way the data never goes near your SD card.

---

As regards the third - incomplete images still being captured - you can leverage the `--exec` option of `fswebcam` to get around this. Basically, you capture to one file and then after it is complete, you use `--exec` to rename the file to `/tmp/latest.jpg` and you use that in your application.

```
fswebcam -r 640x480 --loop 1 --exec 'mv /tmp/inprogress.jpg /tmp/latest.jpg' /tmp/inprogress.jpg
```

This relies on the fact that, under Unix at least, renaming a file does not affect any process that has that file open and that renaming is atomic. So your application will always either get either the entire new or the entire old file and never half a file still being written.

My camera produces images around 160kB, so I tested the file size like this in a tight loop, reading the file as fast as possible and only notifying me if it is far less than the normal size, i.e. truncated:

```
while : ; do l=$(wc -c < latest.jpg); [[ $l -lt 140000 ]] && echo $l; done
```

Comment: How did you get on with this? Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

Try to profile your code (using `cProfile` e.g.) to ensure that issue is not in python interpreter start-up time or `imwrite`. 
If the issue in a camera initialization, then I suppose that the only options is to write a daemon that will keep camera online and give you an image at your request

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I wanted to take 2560x1440 videos with my Raspberry Pi 4 (instead of taking still images like in your case), for which it seemed to be too slow.

However, the solution was to use `ffmepg` to first record a raw video in .mkv format and then convert it to .mp4. I would assume if this solution works for 2560x1440 videos, it should also work with still images.

It turned out that the problem in my case wasn't taking the video itself but the encoding* that happens when `ffmepg` tried to convert the video while recording it.

* If that's the correct term.