# Sending a file using sockets in Python, only while the file is not being modified

Tags: python, json, sockets

I am sending a JSON file over the local network to another computer. However the file is being constantly modified on my first computer. When I try sending it using sockets in Python, it always throws a JSON decode error because the file was modified during sending.  Is there something in Python to check for changes in the file, and say, maybe after .5 seconds of not detecting changes, only then send the file using a callback function that only then executes the socket send method?  For example, something similar to `fs.watchFile`(npm)?
The file is being modified every ~1-2 seconds

Comment: try the `inotify` library. Or read the file several times and make sure they are the same.

Comment: It is probably a lot cleaner to modify the program overwriting the JSON if you have control over it. See third part of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58878512/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell That did the trick

Comment: Cool - feel free to write it up for everyone to see and accept your own answer and grab the points.